# include .obj file to project in Visual Studio by #pragma in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pragma, object-files

is there any way to import .obj file to project by #pragma? I know that is posible to include .lib file, but I don´t find way to include .obj file. 
Problem is, that I have Windows appliaction and for that application I have another test project. I add dependencies to test project. I also add include file to test project, so that I see files from Windows application. But when I want to use some class or method from Windows Application, the linker said that has "unresolved external symbol". Ok, I find .obj files from Windows application and add them to Additional dependencies. And now it´s work. But it´s uncomfortable to each new class, that I create, go to properties of test project and add that file. In additional, when I often delet old classes and add new.

So I hope, that there is another way to do it. Like with .lib files.

Or is there another better way to do it? Here is my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Kowalsky95/Demo). I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks for help and sorry my English :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no way for this. `#pragma comment` can only take `dll` and `lib`, although you could try `obj` if you wish..

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn´t work :(
And go to project properties, because of one new class is annoying :(

Comment: #pragma comment(lib, "foo.obj") works just fine, hard to see the problem.

Comment: Could you please download repository and try it there? I still have problem with that :( I don´t know why :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I fannly solve it. I created small script, thats look into window application folder for all *.obj files, then it change the .vcxproj file, which is actualy .xml file with config. 
Then I connect this script with post build event (*Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Build Events -> Post-Build event*) of windows application.

In every build, VS says that something was changed, and if you want to reaload it. Click to reaload and this is all.

Its work fine for me, at least for now.

https://github.com/Kowalsky95/VisualStudioObjDependencyAdding